# Pragmatically enable GPS from AlertBox

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, gps, xamarin.android

I built an Android app using C# on Xamarin Platform Visual Studio.
I am trying to build an AlertDialog that allows the user to Enable GPS directly from the app. Or even send him to the location settings. So far i have this code that checks if GPS in enabled or not. All i need is how to make an OnClick button on AlertDialog that even enables GPS from app or opens settings.

```
 LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)GetSystemService(Context.LocationService);
        bool gps_enabled = false;
        bool network_enabled = false;
        gps_enabled = lm.IsProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GpsProvider);
        network_enabled = lm.IsProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NetworkProvider);
if (!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dialog.SetTitle("Warning");
            dialog.SetMessage("Your phone location is not enabled" + "\n" + "Please enable your location and run SpeedReport again");
            dialog.SetPositiveButton("Enable", (object sender1, DialogClickEventArgs e1) => {/*i guess i need to enter some code here*/});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this one:
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/Android.Provider.Settings.ActionLocationSourceSettings/

You have to write something like:

```
var locationIntent = new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionLocationSourceSettings);
locationIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
context.StartActivity(locationIntent);
```